# How can I Develop the Self-Discipline to Write Properly

Tags: self-discipline, writing-process

I seldom follow the writing process, usually focusing on rhythm and editing as I write, and giving up quickly, most often producing an unclear, unrhythmical, unflowing, incomplete, disorganized work. How do I develop the self-discipline to follow the writing process, and not to give up till I've started crafting professional quality works, my self-discipline being now so poor I can hardly pray to God anymore?

Comment: Can you say what '… the writing process…' is?

Can you say why you focus on rhythm?

Can you say why editing could be a problem, other than interrupting the flow? 

Instead of giving up, why not set a time, or a number of pages and write to that without stopping, remembering that what you write matters not at all? Every time you hit a block, write 'blank' or any meaningless term you prefer… just do not stop!

Please either explain how prayer comes into this, or drop it.

Comment: In my mind, rhythm is simply the grouping of stressed and unstressed syllables in a piece of writing that give it a certain sound. I think that more generally, one can attend to the full intonation of syllables, which includes more sound qualities such as pitch and duration.

Comment: Thanks and that's far too general for me to follow… and still, can you say what '… the writing process…' means?

To you, what would a clear, rhythmical, flowing, complete or organized work look like? Can you cite and titles that particularly or writers who generally seem admirable?

Comment: I forgot to answer your other questions. I have free-writing more lately, albeit not without stopping, and I seem to be improving at it. Thank you for your advice

Comment: The reason I focus on rhythm is because I enjoy hearing the sound of rhythmic language, and I want to replicate that in my writing and share it with the reader, hoping that they will enjoy it as well.

Comment: Just about any well-written composition, short or long, especially literary masterpieces, have these qualities. I usually just read the KJV Bible a little when I feel like it. That book sounding different  from all other writing, I feel as though it has superior rhythmic quality.

Comment: I do not intend to criticize anyone or anyone's writing, but I would like to encourage both myself and others to set high goals in all they want to accomplish, although not to the point of blasphemy, sacrilage or ungodliness. Sorry for mentioning religion. I will just say that knowledge and skill is necessary for achieving ambitions, and morality must be considered.

Comment: Thanks and are you saying the KJV Bible is your main source of literary inspiration? Perhaps your only source?

Again, can you say what '… the writing process…' means? To you, what would a clear, rhythmical, flowing, complete or organized work look like? Can you cite any titles that particularly or writers who generally seem admirable?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever read The Book of Disquiet by: Fernando Pessoa? I also am looking for ways of developing self discipline; not just regarding my writing habit, but in all areas of my life.

Learning about Pessoa gave me the confidence to accept and understand my own pace and ability for structure and dedication.

There is a video called [The Terrible Paradox of Self Awareness](https://youtu.be/6qU1sDBU9Cs?si=_uI8d-G441hgMuPK) by a content creator on YouTube called [The Pursuit of Wonder](https://youtube.com/@PursuitofWonder?si=y6IbmFollEqfHFpJ).

The analysis and discussion of that book in his video gave me the feeling that self discipline develops you from within as much as you develop it through tending to your habits and rituals.

Rolling a boulder up a hill may constitute discipline in some peoples eyes, but in Camus’ view, “One must imagine Sisyphus happy”.

If you approach the boulder with fear or trepidation, it will eternally crush you. That is why you need to assess your approach to the boulder and make changes where possible. Your obstacles, are your responsibility.

I realize this is more of a pep talk than an answer, but your question resonated with me personally and I felt the need to offer this response.

I guess my answer is that if you can’t find the tools necessary to unleash your own self discipline, then it’s best to start looking seriously at great writers and to divine your answer through a practice inquiry and contemplation.

Step 1: Inquire
Example: How can I develop the self-discipline to write properly?

Step 2: Contemplate
Example: How CAN I develop the self-discipline to write properly?

In the second step, the emphasis on the word “can” is intended to trigger your brain to start thinking creatively. You will receive an answer from this practice. It may not be the answer you want but it might be the answer you need.

“The struggle itself toward the heights is enough to fill a man’s heart. One must imagine Sisyphus happy.”
-Albert Camus, *The Myth of Sisyphus*

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you're having a writing problem.

1. Is writing important enough to you to give up on comfort, relaxation, and the freedom to do whatever you want to do, however you want to do it? Writing is hard work and the journey is full of hardship and disappointment. Is writing more important to you than having an easy time? Do you *have* to write, no matter what, or you would be deeply unappy?
2. If writing is important to you, writing must be your number one priority in life (only behind earning a living and taking care of your family). Nothing else must come before it. You have to do it, even if you don't feel like it. Even if other people think you should have time for them. Make writing your top priority and don't let anything come between you and writing, unless it is a matter of life and death.
3. Make writing a habit. Find a fixed timespan every workday and write during that time. (Research, development, etc. are a part of writing and will take place during this time, too.)
4. If you are unsatisfied with what you wrote, revise it, if you understand what is wrong and think it can be corrected, otherwise move on to the next piece. Don't get stuck on your first novel for ever. Writing is a skill that needs to be trained, no matter what level you are on, so be prepared for many failures before you eventually succeed for the first time. Writing the next novel is a better learning experience than endless revisions of what may well be a fundamental failure or too difficult for your current ability. Put it in a drawer and come back to it later, if you still find it worthwhile.
5. If you have AD(H)D, see a psychotherapist and/or psychiatrist and get psychotherapy and/or medication. Medication isn't for everyone, but many find it greatly enhances their ability to focus and stick with what they are doing. If you don't have psychological problems, and you sill find you cannot bring yourself to invest the necessary time and energy, maybe writing is not for you.